# Como comparar classe Date com System.currentTimeMillis() em Java?

Tags: java, datetime

Como comparar se um objeto Date, por exemplo "2014-01-29 00:00:00" é maior que a data do sistema atual, por exemplo `System.currentTimeMillis()` em Java?

Eu gostaria de fazer algo como o trecho abaixo, mas não funcionou:

```
if (object.getDate().getSeconds() > System.currentTimeMillis())
  //do something
```

Comment: Esse trecho de código é a resposta ou uma tentativa que não funcionou?

Comment: Uma tentativa fracassada.

Comment: Obrigado por esclarecer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Existem duas formas simples:

## Comparando o tempo em milissegundos

O método `getTime()` do `java.util.Date` retorna o tempo em milissegundos deste 1 de janeiro de 1970. O mesmo ocorre com o método `currentTimeMillis()`. Então, basta comparar os dois números:

```java
if (object.getDate().getTime() > System.currentTimeMillis()) { ... }
```

## Criando um `Date` com a data do sistema

Ao criar um `new Date()`, o construtor inicializa a data com a data do sistema. Veja a implementação:

```java
public Date() {
    this(System.currentTimeMillis());
}
```

Portanto, basta verificar se sua data é maior, assim:

```java
if (object.getDate().after(new Date())) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

Faça da seguinte maneira:

```
if (object.getDate().after(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
    // do something
```

Mas o certo mesmo se você está usando Java abaixo da versão 8 é largar mão do `Date` e usar a biblioteca [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/). :)

Comment: Concordando com a resposta acima, Joda é muito mais simples para manipular e validar datas. Alem disso, você já vai se acostumando com a lógica até que a nova API de Datas Java 8 seja liberada oficialmente.